# To get the url name and redirect in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code for getting the current URL in jQuery.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
```

Now I have got the url like this

```
http://localhost/TantraProjects/CollectiveCraft/Repo/WebSite/index.php/crafts/t-lights.html
```

I want to convert the URL into this

```
http://localhost/TantraProjects/CollectiveCraft/Repo/WebSite/index.php
```

Is there any a way to convert into URL as above, whatever the URL is ?

Comment: Redirecting the page using JS/jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will always get index.php in your url and you want to remove everything after index.php, following code will work:

```
var url='http://localhost/TantraProjects/CollectiveCraft/Repo/WebSite/index.php/crafts/t-lights.html';
var b= url.split('index.php');
var newurl=b[0]+'index.php';
document.write(newurl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not ideal but you can something like this

```
var str = "http://localhost/TantraProjects/CollectiveCraft/Repo/WebSite/index.php/crafts/t-lights.html";

var modUrl = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("php") + 3);
alert(modUrl);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JmLq9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var url = "http://localhost/TantraProjects/CollectiveCraft/Repo/WebSite/index.php/crafts/t-lights.html";
var ind = url.replace(url.split('.php')[1],'');
alert(ind);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VhbA4/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var regex=/(.+\.php)\/(.+)/
var matches=regex.exec(url);//matches[1] contains the result
```